# How to dynamically change the children in a view in a vsc extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The code examples for TreeDataProviders on github sometimes show a refresh method but I'm not sure how to use it. Do I just call refresh() and pass in the data to be used by getChildren() and just update the class property that getChildren uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `refresh()` function usually triggers the `onDidChangeTreeData` even, to which the base class (`TreeDataProvider`) is listening. It will then call `getChildren` again to re-fill the tree. See also the description of that event:

```ts
/**
 * An optional event to signal that an element or root has changed.
 * This will trigger the view to update the changed element/root and its children recursively (if shown).
 * To signal that root has changed, do not pass any argument or pass `undefined` or `null`.
 */
onDidChangeTreeData?: Event<T | undefined | null>;
```

You can design the refresh function as you like, e.g. passing in new data, or you keep a reference to an applicationm data provider in the tree provider (e.g. passed to it in the c-tor). Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods on the [`TreeDataProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeDataProvider%3CT%3E) that are important to know about...

1. `getChildren` - method to obtain the data for items that will be displayed in the tree. This should return an array -- don't worry about turning the data into a [`TreeItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItem) yet, this is just raw data.
2. `getTreeItem` - called on each item in the array returned by `getChildren`. Should return a single [`TreeItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItem) using the data provided..
3. `onDidChangeTreeData` - a [`vscode.Event`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Event%3CT%3E) that, when changed, will trigger `getChildren` to be re-evaluated. This can be done by creating a [`vscode.EventEmitter`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#EventEmitter%3CT%3E)(let's call it `eventEmitter`) and calling the `fire` method on the `eventEmitter`. This will cause the `eventEmitter.event` to be updated/triggered.

Here is an example of how to set up a [`TreeDataProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeDataProvider%3CT%3E), that I hope will help illustrate how to create the `EventEmitter`, set the `TreeDataProvider`'s `onDidChangeTreeData` property to the event of the `EventEmitter`, and create/export a refresh method that can be called to trigger an update of the data.

#### TreeDataProvider

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export class AccountsProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<Account> {
  private accounts: Array<Account>;
  constructor() {
    this.accounts = getAccounts();
  }

  _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<undefined> =
    new vscode.EventEmitter<undefined>();
  onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<undefined> =
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

  refresh(): void {
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire(undefined);
  }

  getTreeItem(a: Account): vscode.TreeItem {
    return new AccountTreeItem(
      a.name,
      a.id,
      a,
      vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None
    );
  }

  getChildren(): Thenable<Account[] | undefined> {
    this.accounts = getAccounts();

    if (this.accounts) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.accounts);
    }

    return Promise.resolve([]);
  }
}
```

#### TreeItem

```
export class AccountTreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {
  constructor(
    public readonly name: string,
    public readonly id: string,
    public readonly accountData: Account,
    public readonly collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
    public readonly iconPath: string = new vscode.ThemeIcon('account'),
    public readonly contextValue: string = 'accountTreeItem'
  ) {
    super(name, collapsibleState);
    this.tooltip = `Active Account: ${accountData.name}`;
  }
}
```

#### Importing and triggering refresh method

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { AccountsProvider } from 'accountsProvider'; // The TreeDataProvider

const accountProvider = new AccountsProvider();
context.subscriptions.push(
  vscode.commands.registerCommand('ext.accounts.refresh', () => {
    accountProvider.refresh();
  })
);

vscode.commands.executeCommand('ext.accounts.refresh');
```